# PHP SOAP not including my parameters in request

Tags: php, soap

I'm trying to access the HelloWorldCredentials service on

`https://statistik.uni-c.dk/instregws/DataServiceXML.asmx?op=HelloWorldCredentials`

I have the necessary credentials.

As far as I can see, I need to submit an array called "Credentials" containing one array containing two strings, one called "Username" and one called "Password".

I build my array like this:

```
$params = array(
    "Credentials" => array(
        "Username" => "Obviously",
        "Password" => "NotPublic",
    )
);
```

However, when I execute

```
$client = new SoapClient("https://statistik.uni-c.dk/instregws/DataServiceXML.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
$params = array(
    "Credentials" => array(
        "Username" => "Obviously",
        "Password" => "NotPublic",
    )
);
$response = $client->__soapCall("HelloWorldCredentials", array($params));

echo("*** PARAMS ***\n");
var_dump( $params );

echo("\n*** REQUEST ***\n");
echo( $client->__getLastRequest() );

echo("\n*** RESPONSE ***\n");
var_dump( $response );
```

I get

```
*** PARAMS ***
array(1) {
  ["Credentials"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Username"]=>
    string(11) "Obviously"
    ["Password"]=>
    string(8) "NotPublic"
  }
}
```

-as I should, but

```
*** REQUEST ***
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://statistik.uni-c.dk/instreg/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:HelloWorldCredentials/>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

So obviously I get

```
*** RESPONSE ***
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["HelloWorldCredentialsResult"]=>
  string(19) "Missing credentials"
}
```

Why are my parameters completely absent from the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to the WSDL for the [HelloWorldCredentials](https://statistik.uni-c.dk/instRegWS/DataServiceXML.asmx?op=HelloWorldCredentials) method you need to send the Credentials in the `Header` not the `Body` of the soap `Envelope`

so this should work:

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient("https://statistik.uni-c.dk/instregws/DataServiceXML.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));

$credentials = array(
    'Username' => 'Obviously',
    'Password' => 'NotPublic'
);    
$header = new SoapHeader('http://statistik.uni-c.dk/instreg/', 'Credentials', $credentials);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($header);

$response = $client->HelloWorldCredentials();

echo("\n*** REQUEST ***\n");
echo( $client->__getLastRequest() );

echo("\n*** RESPONSE ***\n");
var_dump( $response );
```

Comment: Gah. Thank you SO much! :-) Why would they put it in the header...?